# What are the most interesting historical sites to visit in Salt Lake City, Utah?

Tags: usa, budget, sightseeing, utah, salt-lake-city

My wife and I are visiting Salt Lake City in the near future and want to see the most interesting historical sites the city has to offer.

Our budget is low, so things that are free/cheap would be best, but if something is particularly interesting, we can pay a hundred or so dollars.

What are the most interesting historical things to visit in Salt Lake City, Utah, with a low budget?

Comment: Welcome to the Travel.SE. I think this question is very broad, but I want to wait a community reaction on this.

Comment: @Kalamane: Hi, welcome to Travel.SE and to concur with VMatm, could you please try to make the question more specific by telling what sort of sights exactly you're interested in?

Comment: Very broad.  I could just quote http://wikitravel.org/en/Salt_Lake_City, but perhaps some interests you have - be it musical, outdoorsy, artsy, thrill-seeking - any specific things you are after?

Comment: I've narrowed this down to historical sites.

Comment: **Forget the history!!** Get your ass skiiing, man - the greatest snow on Earth, no doubt.  You mention not wanting to spend a lot of money - you're in the right place, as the State is family-oriented.  **Get yourself out hiking** ... what about **hike up Mt Olympus, it's great!** for a starter.  SLC and Utah is also the greatest hiking on earth, greatest everything-outdoors on earth! Enjoy!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For free, you can't miss **[Temple Square](http://www.visittemplesquare.com/)**.

[image] <sup>(photo from [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/danniao/1182108215/sizes/m/in/photostream/))</sup>

The grounds themselves are beautiful just to walk around or for a photo-op (including views of the Salt Lake Temple itself as well as reflecting pools and countless gardens) but there are a [number of attractions](http://www.visittemplesquare.com/attractions) to visit and/or tour, too.  Some of the highlights:

- **[Joseph Smith Memorial Building](http://lds.org/placestovisit/eng/historical-sites/joseph-smith-memorial-building)** — Two restaurants, tours, and a [free showing of *Joseph Smith: The Prophet of the Restoration*](http://lds.org/church/events/temple-square-events/joseph-smith-the-prophet-of-the-restoration?lang=eng) at the **Legacy Theater**.
- **[The Beehive House](http://lds.org/placestovisit/eng/historical-sites/historic-beehive-house-on-temple-square)** — A home of Brigham Young (second president of the LDS Church and first governor of Utah).  The home is well-preserved and the tour is very interesting.  It really gives you a feel for 19th century living (of a statesman, of course).
- **[Church Office Building](http://lds.org/placestovisit/eng/historical-sites/historic-beehive-house-on-temple-square)** — great view of the Salt Lake Valley from the observation deck of this 26-story building.
- **[Salt Lake Tabernacle](http://lds.org/placestovisit/eng/historical-sites/salt-lake-tabernacle-on-temple-square)**
- **[North Visitor's Center](http://lds.org/placestovisit/eng/visitors-centers/temple-square-north-visitors-center)** — the highlight is a beautiful replica of [the Christus](http://www.christusstatue.com/).

#### Ensign Peak

[image] <sup>(view from Ensign Peak, photo from [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/andrewasmith/5821947732/sizes/m/in/photostream/))</sup>

[Ensign Peak](http://www.utah.com/thingtodo23540.htm) has a great view and is a short and easy hike just minutes from downtown Salt Lake City.

#### This is the Place park

[This is the Place Heritage Park](http://www.thisistheplace.org/) consists of a monument to the [Mormon pioneers' arrival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mormon_pioneers) in the Salt Lake Valley, as well as a visitor's center/shop and a village of preserved pioneer homes.  There is a small admission fee.